# Visual Studio shows "Updating source control status" after installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, asp.net-mvc-4

After installing ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta, Visual Studio shows "Updating source control status" on the lower left side of the status area.

Any ideas? Seems a lot of stuff is broken after installing the beta. I am trying [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403477/invalidcastexception-is-thrown-after-installing-asp-net-mvc-4-beta) **not** uninstalling it.. :(

Comment: that does not seem like something that should be related to MVC. could you describe in more detail in what circumstances this is hapenning.

Comment: exactly after installing the beta.

Comment: So that message is there all the time? When youre creating a project? During compilation?

Comment: It is when loading a solution. It seems it goes off to TFS for every file in every nuget package. It causes VS to lock up and become unresponsive whenever the project is loaded up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue is Nuget Manager. It installs templates for both ASP 4 and ASP 2.

Uninstalled Nuget Manager and then re-installed it (reopen VS Studio) and solutions come up in few seconds

Comment: This fixed the issue for me with: NuGet 1.6, ASP.Net MVC 4.0 Beta templates.  Uninstalling removed the MVC 4.0 Beta template projects (and those of Asp.Net Web pages 2 also).  I reinstalled MVC for with Web installer and the ASP.Net MVC 4.0 Beta templates have not returned.

Comment: Uninstalled NuGet v.1.6 and installed latest v1.8 - works like a charm... THANKS!!!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same exact problem!  It seems to take forever to deal with TFS when opening a project.

I already uninstalled it once to verify (yes, it solved the problem). Now, I've re-installed and it came back with a vengeance. VS.NET locked up with loading my project :(

I'll post more if I get anywhere...

UPDATE: I waited longer and VS.NET wasn't locked up, it just took a really long time (5 minutes or so).

It seems that it's related to NuGet packages somehow, since my Source Control window has almost 1200 messages like this:

> The item $/...[snip].../packages/AmplifyJS.1.0.0 already exists.
>   The item $/...[snip].../packages/AmplifyJS.1.0.0/AmplifyJS.1.0.0.nupkg already exists.

Every message in there is "already exists" for something in the NuGet "packages" folder

I'll keep you posted

UPDATE 2: I added a ["Connect"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/726314/mvc-4-beta-causes-problems-with-tfs-and-nuget) bug.  Go there and verify that you can see it too to get it more attention.

Comment: Well.. I left it overnight and still. So what I did was: Restore Windows from latest backup. :(

Comment: I've spoken to a number of people with the same problem. Hopefully MS is looking into it.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on the machines I have installed MVC 4 beta on.

Comment: MS is aware of the problem as Jim Lamb stated above.

Answer (score 2):

As Sonali pointed out, the issue is related to NuGet. On solution open, the NuGet package manager does a version control operation for every file in your "packages" directory. This issue should be fixed any day now in their 1.7 release by making it a one time bulk operation.

In the meantime, if you're using VS11 with TFS11, you can upgrade your workspace to a "local" workspace to eliminate the delay on solution open.

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing the same problem when opening projects...delays up to 10 minutes while the solution was loading.  Our only solution after trying many suggested solutions via web searching, was to purge all deleted files for the project(s) in source control.  Different solutions for different people seem to exist but if nothing else has worked, then maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding this problem in VS2013 Ultimate, but was not seeing the Nuget messages mentioned in other replies. The consistent message is "Updating source control status...", which can take upwards of 10 minutes to complete. It occurs at what seems like random intervals - I could be opening a solution, or typing out code, and UI lockup with the above message.

The solution that appears to be working for me now is to edit the devenv.exe.config file. Details can be found [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/810666/visual-studio-2013-intolerably-slow-when-using-tfs-source-control).

Essentially you add one line to disable the default proxy. I hope this helps someone else.