# Expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory' cannot be used for return type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am getting this error when I try to run a project that I took over.

I assume I have a problem in my *web.config*, but I don't know what to look for.

> Expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory' cannot be 
>       used for return type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory'

Any suggestions on the same are highly appreciated.

Comment: This smacks of the version the webpages assembly being pointed at version 1.0.0.0 for mvc3 instead of 2.0.0.0 for mvc4, some more info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-not-found

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try to replace line in Web.Config

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

to

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

(set MvcWebRazorHostFactory to version 4.0.0.0)

Comment: When using Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage -Pre set MvcWebRazorHostFactory to version 5.0.0.0.

Comment: I had other places that needed fixes too. Like Slicksim suggested

Comment: I found it useful to open References find System.Web.Mvc and check the AssemblyVersion (this is the version number to use). Otherwise changing as explained here works.

Comment: Note that there are two Web.Config files. I had to change the one under the project "Views" directory, not the one at the project root.

Comment: This didn't work when I upgraded from MVC 3 to 4, but after spending way too long trying to find a missing reference to factoryType, I gave up and upgraded again to MVC 5. Then I manually switched the version from 4.0.0.0 to 5.0.0.0, and it worked! thanks!
Now my app can't load WebGrease… :-/

Answer (score 36):

Set MvcWebRazorHostFactory to version **5**.0.0.0 in ALL Views/web.config
Under

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: I guess it depends on your version.  5.0.0.0 worked for me.  Ditto.

Comment: Thank you, can confirm if you are getting this issue, and you're running mvc5, then this will be your fix, also ensure you've set all your webpages to 3.0.0 (use this post as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403477/invalidcastexception-is-thrown-after-installing-asp-net-mvc-4-beta)

Comment: This really just needs to correspond to the System.Web.Mvc reference version.

Answer (score 8):

For everybody else still suffering, my solution was just like the one above, but with a **tweak** - I needed to match factory type version with version of System.Web.Mvc dll in your project references. To find out which version you have:

1. Expand "References" in your project
2. Right-click on System.Web.Mvc and look at version

   [image]
3. Update web.config in your **Views folder**

So in my case it was as below:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: Best Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.  What worked for me:
Right-click on your project and select Manage NuGet Packages.  Install Microsoft ASP.NET Razor.  Rebuild the project.