# The expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory' can not be used for return type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a website developed in MVC 3, and trying to open with Visual Studio 2012, it updates the project and try to run the project, it gives the error:

```
The expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory' can not be used for return type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory'
```

System.Web.Mvc updated the DLL to version 4.0.0.1.

#### Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Main" connectionString="Data Source=sacteste;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=automa;Password=auto2020;Unicode=True"
            providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="AssuntoEmailNotas" value="Nota fiscal emitida"/>
        <add key="TemplateEmailNotas" value="C:\DotNet\PIF\GestaoNFSe\templateNFSe.cshtml"/>
        <add key="TemplateEmailCobranca" value="C:\DotNet\PIF\GestaoNFSe\templateCartaCobranca.cshtml"/>
        <add key="EmailFromEndereco" value="desenvolvimento@megasul.com.br"/>
        <add key="EmailFromNome" value="Megasul"/>
        <add key="ChaveCriptografia" value="_nfse_megasul#1234"/>
        <!-- alterar a chave invalida todos os e-mails já enviados! -->
        <add key="DiretorioLicencasCobreBem" value="C:\CobreBemX\"/>
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
        <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
    </appSettings>
  <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership defaultProvider="MegaMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="MegaMembershipProvider" applicationName="WebRAT" type="MegaControls.Membership.MegaMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Main"
                    enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0"
                    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" passwordFormat="Clear"/>
                <!--119746-->
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="192.168.0.201" defaultCredentials="false" userName="jani" password="jani"></network>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the Web.config file located in your Views folder and change the factorytype version to 5.0.0.0 as of October 26, 2015.

i.e

From

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

To

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: How is this going to help him?  He said his MVC version was 3 and he just upgraded to 4.  You're telling him to reference version 5.  If he's not using version 5, your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @ELMOJO I have mentioned the date because I want him to upgrade it to the version 5 and if he still chose to use the version 4, he can still get the idea that which sections needs to be updated.

Comment: Just because YOU want him to upgrade to version 5 doesn't mean he can upgrade to 5.  He or his organization may not be ready or willing to upgrade to version 5.

Comment: @ELMOJO you are not trying to get the point and I think you are new here.

Comment: The point is to answer the question he asked not demand that he upgrade.  Further, you are asking him to change a line in his web.config that he doesn't even have.  Look at the code he posted.  That line doesn't appear in the web.config he posted.  Maybe it should, but maybe you understand what it is you are posting before copying and pasting someone else's answer from another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617625/expression-of-type-system-web-mvc-mvcwebrazorhostfactory-cannot-be-used-for-re).