# Routing not working for MVC application under a Webforms website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing, virtual-directory

I'm creating a Reporting application in MVC that I want to use in multiple websites. I want to be able to simply create an application in IIS under each of the consuming websites and point them to the same directory where the Reporting application is located.

When I tried doing this in an MVC website it worked fine. However, when I tried adding this application under a Webforms website I got a "403.14 - Forbidden" error because it's trying to use the Static File handler.

How can I correct it to use the right handler to route to the Home controller?

Comment: I'm just trying to do research on Google right now to see 'what' to try. I can tell the problem has to do with it using the "StaticFile" handler instead of the asp.net routing engine (whatever it's formally called).

Comment: I've had no issues combining the two, but there is a little setup work: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx  or http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Comment: @BrianMains Thanks, but if I'm not mistaken those articles are about integrating MVC into existing Webform apps. I've done that before and it works great, but this time I'm actually trying to add a completely separate MVC application under an existing Webforms website (i.e. sort of like a virtual directory, but as an application).

Comment: have you tried to use a classic routing?

Comment: You can try this [setup described by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx) - which seems doable in your case because you're preventing the "child" (MVC virtual app under existing web forms app) from inheriting config from it's "parent". Hth..

Comment: @EdSF Hmm... I tried but doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if a) does a virtual application actually inherit web.config settings from the root site? and b) is the issue maybe the other way around; that is, perhaps I need to edit the root website to make it use the routing engine somehow? I want to try the latter, but need to do some research to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the base website's app pool was using the 2.0 clr. Once I realized this I made the necessary web.config adjustments and recompiled the app to run under the 4.0 clr and then everything worked.

I also have a bunch of `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` sections. Not sure if those are necessary now, but I'm leaving them since it works and the sub app doesn't need to inherit anything from the base website.

This post ([Expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory' cannot be used for return type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617625/expression-of-type-system-web-mvc-mvcwebrazorhostfactory-cannot-be-used-for-re)) also helped me in trying to get the web.config stuff sorted out while converting from 2.0 to 4.0. That was kind of a pain because there were several errors I had to work through, but I think I mostly just had to remove some sections of the web.config that are no longer necessary (because they're now included in the machine config).