# Exception after installing ASP.NET Route Debugger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, visual-studio-2013

i am running VS 2013 and i just installed the [ASP.NET Route Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx). when I try to run it by browsing to localhost:xxx/rd i get the following error:

```
[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84448590\ee78b185\assembly\dl3\776eeced\61921913_e997ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.
Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET 
Files\root\84448590\ee78b185\assembly\dl3\776eeced\61921913_e997ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84448590\ee78b185\assembly\dl3\776eeced\61921913_e997ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.]
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.GetRazorSection(String virtualPath) +151
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +209
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath) +46
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig() +58
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host() +65
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +83
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +54
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +15
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9949713
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) +10
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +480
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +123
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +582
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +140
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +63
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +49
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9631512
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

i tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404019/411094) but it did not work. i tried making it version 2 and 3.

Comment: Just a hunch based on the exception message. Clearly there seems to be one part of your code referencing `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` v2.0.0.0, while another part of your code is referencing `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` v3.0.0.0. Could it be that the ASP.NET Route Debugger has a dependency on the older version of the .dll but your project is using the newer one? The post you linked seems like one way to force your project to use an older version; you should post the error message from when you put v2.0.0.0 in the config. Could it be that you forgot to delete the v3.0.0.0 .dll from your bin?

Answer (score 5):

roliu pointed me in the right direction and i figured it out.  the route debugger has a web.config file which references the v2.0.0.0 version of system.web.webpages.razor and v4.0.0.0 of mvc.  i changed all refereces of razor v2 to razor v3 and changes mvc 4 to mvc 5.

Comment: Fyi, this Web.config file resides within Areas/RouteDebugger/Views.